# Format gcloud compute instances list to get single metadata value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

As part of some GCP admin automation I'm trying to run a gcloud compute instances list command to return a few instance properties, one of which is a single metadata property. I cannot find in the documentation how to return only a single metadata property.

This is what I would think is correct based on the doc, but I don't get any metadata properties returned...

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="name~^my-machine.*-type" --zones=zone1,zone2,zone3 --format="json(name,metadata.items.MY_VALUE)"
```

How can I return a single metadata value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eesh... this was **not** obvious ;-)

```sh
KEY=...

gcloud compute instances list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(metadata.items.extract("${KEY}"))"
```

See [`extract`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections#extract)

I'm not sure why it works.

In my case:

```sh
gcloud compute instances list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(metadata.items)"
```

Yields:

```
{'key': 'gce-container-declaration', 'value': "..."};
{'key': 'google-logging-enabled', 'value': 'true'}
```

> **NOTE** a semi-colon separated list of JSON objects

So, `metadata.items` appears to be a list of JSON objects `{"key": $KEY, "value": $VALUE}` and I think this why you can't walk down through the values using something ... `metadata.items.key["google-logging-enabled"]` or similar.

When I initially looked using YAML, this wasn't obvious and I think, even though the YAML looks flat, the items are embedded and the `--format=yaml` is doing something clever:

```sh
gcloud compute instances list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="yaml(metadata.items)"
---
metadata:
  items:
  - key: gce-container-declaration
    value: |-
      ...
  - key: google-logging-enabled
    value: 'true'
```

But:

```sh
gcloud compute instances list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(metadata.items.extract("gce-container-declaration"))"
```

Yields:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: instance-1
      image: ...
      stdin: false
      tty: false
  restartPolicy: Always
```